# Flutter Amplify / Applying app after 'save and deploy' in model

Tags: flutter, datastore, aws-amplify

I have already modified models in cloud.
and I did 'save and deploy' too.

after that, what should i do to sync with my app??

Answer (score 0):

You have to pull it using `amplify pull`.